# How can I set a Post's default visibility to private and pending review checked

Tags: posts, post-status

there are 2 things I'd like to do:
1. set a post's visibility to private by default.

I've been looking around the web for a code or even a plugin that lets me do this. The problem I've run into is that the codes no longer work.

2. set the pending review checkbox to true as well?

If someone can point me in the right direction, Id appreciate it.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this snippet after more searching:

```
//Force posts of custom type to be private
//…but first make sure they are not 'trash' otherwise it is impossible to trash a post
function force_type_private($post)
{
    if (($post['post_type'] == 'post')

    {
    if ($post['post_status'] != 'trash') $post['post_status'] = 'private';
    }
    return $post;
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'force_type_private');
```

Changed the boolean to:

```
if (($post['post_type'] == 'post')&&(!current_user_can('administrator')))
```

This makes sure only admin can publish.